# Custom info window with address

Tags: java, android, android-studio, google-maps-markers, infowindow

I'm trying to show the location of the user in a nice little box like below. Currently I only have a ".title()" on my marker so I am not sure on how to create a blue, transparent box with the following information:

http://s32.postimg.org/v6z9yaamd/Untitled.png

I already have the current longitude and latitude of the user and I'm guessing you can get the users address via Google. If you know how to style the infowindow and/or how to show the address any help would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Here you have updated code for infowindow

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback {

    GoogleMap Map;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // Getting reference to the SupportMapFragment of activity_main.xml
        SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);

        // Getting GoogleMap object from the fragment
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);

        // Setting a custom info window adapter for the google map

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onMapReady(final GoogleMap googleMap) {
        this.Map = googleMap;
        Map.setInfoWindowAdapter(new InfoWindowAdapter() {

            // Use default InfoWindow frame
            @Override
            public View getInfoWindow(Marker arg0) {
                return null;
            }

            // Defines the contents of the InfoWindow
            @Override
            public View getInfoContents(Marker arg0) {

                // Getting view from the layout file info_window_layout
                View v = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.info_window_layout, null);

                // Getting the position from the marker
                LatLng latLng = arg0.getPosition();

                // Getting reference to the TextView to set latitude
                TextView tvLat = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tv_lat);

                // Getting reference to the TextView to set longitude
                TextView tvLng = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tv_lng);

                // Setting the latitude
                tvLat.setText("Latitude:" + latLng.latitude);

                // Setting the longitude
                tvLng.setText("Longitude:" + latLng.longitude);

                // Returning the view containing InfoWindow contents
                return v;

            }

        });


        // Adding and showing marker while touching the GoogleMap
        Map.setOnMapClickListener(new OnMapClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onMapClick(LatLng arg0) {
                // Clears any existing markers from the GoogleMap
                Map.clear();

                // Creating an instance of MarkerOptions to set position
                MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions();

                // Setting position on the MarkerOptions
                markerOptions.position(arg0);

                // Animating to the currently touched position
                Map.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(arg0));

                // Adding marker on the GoogleMap
                Marker marker = Map.addMarker(markerOptions);

                // Showing InfoWindow on the GoogleMap
                marker.showInfoWindow();

            }
        });


    }
}
```